# Meteor passing this to modal

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I have a list

```
{{#each objects}}
  <li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"> {{_name}} </li>
  <li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"> {{_position}} </li>
{{/end}}
```

Where each `<li>` triggers the following modal

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="exampleModal">
   {{> objectTemplate}}
</div>
```

And i want access to `this` inside the template `objectTemplate` to change the attribute i clicked before. So for example i click on the `<li>` with `{{_name}}` the modal should show a text input field where i can change the name.
But to keep things simple, how can i pass `{{_name}}` to the template `objectTemplate` and change it there?

Comment: How are you initializing the modal and displaying it?

Comment: the modal id is "exampleModal" and each li has data-target =exampleModal, which is from bootstrap

Comment: Are the object list and the modal in separate templates? Could you provide a little more context into your template structure?

Comment: yes they are in different templates, i will provide more code

Answer (score 0):

You can use `{{#with ...}}` to set the data context to a single object. For example:

```
{{#each objects}}
  {{#with _name}}
    <li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"> {{this}} </li>
  {{/with}}
  {{#with _position}}
    <li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"> {{this}} </li>
  {{/with}}
{{/end}}
```